# 50 mOhm F SMD resistor identification HELP!

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, resistors, identification, components

I have been trying to identify this resistor so I can order replacements as several are bad in my device. It’s fairly large. 11mm x 5mm? This is an estimate in reference to the nano2 smd 7a fuse in the socket near by and several other components on board. I have provided a picture with the component circled in red. Any help is greatly appreciated. 50mOhmF SMD resistor. .05ohm or 50M ohm? Any part numbers provided for replacement much appreciated. Most of the ones I find are much too small 6mm L x 3mm W. Thanks!!![image]

Comment: How do you know the resistor is bad?

Comment: Well, there are actually two of them melted/bulging in circuit. So.. I suppose it’s an assumption, but also those two stations do not work. So, even if they were to test good, I’d still like to replace them since they are leaking black plastic onto other components.

Comment: I also used my MM to poke around and found 2 of the nano2-SMD 7A fuses were bad, with no continuity.

Comment: That sure looks burned through.  I'd be worried that something else got damaged.

Comment: They don’t look particularly bad to me- that kind of plastic does not melt or leak, it chars and cracks. Looks more like a drop of paint. If the measure a dead short on your lowest ohms range in-circuit they are probably okay. 0.05 ohms. Chances are the power semis are dead, and this would be more or less confirmed  if you replace the fuses and they blow again. And if the power semis are gone, the drivers may also be damaged.

Comment: My bets is that that’s a current sense resistor and them failing is just a symptom of something else and bigger failing.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your insight and suggestions. I really do appreciate it. I will remove the casing on my cadex battery analyzer in the next week and do some more thorough testing and observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the type is SLN5TTED50L0F from KOA Speer (http://www.koaspeer.com/slw07-slw1-sln3-sln5/).
The F stands for 1% tolerance.

Comment: Thank you fallanck for providing a plausible replacement part and link.